# How much spring hibernate effect on memory consumption than pure jsp/servlet?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, memory

I just want to know that I want to web host my web site with cheapest plan. In java plan prices are according to the mainly on heap size(64mb, 128mb, 256mb etc..)  how much we want.

Now before starting my application I just need to know is there will be any effect on memory if I develop web site using spring and hibernate instead of simple jsp/servlet? If yes than how much?

Is it possible to deploy medium sized web application with spring and hibernate with 64mb?

I just got confused when I just run my starting phase application in local tomcat it takes around 350mb of memory that makes me worried about costing when I will going to deploy my web site.

Please give me light in this if anyone has good knowledge about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every library or framework you add/use will add memory usage.

If you want to save money getting the cheapest plan I will recommend you to do a profiling on your app (using VisualVm or something like that) and check how much memory is your app consuming and the most important: where. Then you can try to optimize it, and try to configure your appserver to work only with the memory you want.

Keep in mind that memory consumption will vary also depending on the load of your website.